# How to load a JSP into a div by ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, html

I am trying to update my static web site to a Spring MVC application. I had integrated Spring MVC backend to the application which is working fine.

I was stuck on inject a JSP page into a div now.

The logic is: I press a button in head section (top_frame.html - which embedded an Ajax call) let my controller to check user login status, if the user is not exist in the system, controller return a JSP page (url format) to Ajax call as response body, which is working fine. And then, Ajax do the success function call to load the JSP output into a div. This JSP will generate a user information registration form to let user fill it up, from here, the application will go to MVC work model. my problem is: Seems Ajax never load the JSP properly and the error message as:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/htss/customers/testController.jsp  404 Not Found 18ms
```

I tried access the JSP from url in my browser, I see same result, which means my JSP is not accessible.

There are my system configuration:

in web.xml showing:

```
<servlet>
    <description>generated-servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>htss Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:htss-web-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>htss Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my htss-web-context.xml showing:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
```

my JSP page was populated in folder:

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/pages/customers/
```

my Ajax function in my top_frame.html as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- get login information from controller -->
function createCustomer() {
var contextPath=window.location.pathname;
console.log("Context Path: "+contextPath);
console.log("createCustomer called.");
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'testControllerURL',
    data: ({name : "me"}),
    success: function(data) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('sign_in');
        console.log(elem.ATTRIBUTE_NODE);
        console.log(data);
      <!-- $('#sign_in').load($(data).attr('href')); -->
        $('#sign_in').load(data);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

sign_in is a div in same top_frame.html

my controller showing:

```
/*Added for ajax call response function*/
@RequestMapping(value="/testControllerURL") 
public @ResponseBody String testControllerURL(ModelMap model) {
    String custSequence=getCustomerIdSequence(thsssequenceDAO);
    model.addAttribute("CustSequence",custSequence);
    /*model.addAttribute("commandObjectName", commandObject);*/
    System.out.println("ajax text controller url called.");
    return "customers/testController.jsp";
}
```

Ajax function call works, controller works, but JSP not found, very annoy me.

Please help!!

Update: As I thought, maybe spring mvc not really recognise my JSP, I added some JSP servlet in my web.xml as:

```
<servlet>
    <description>jsp-servlet</description>
            <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but this is nothing changed, JSP is still not found.

As this JSP is a plain JSP, it don't link to any related servlet, it is not really fit in MVC model. Any idea about this sort of issue??

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is this `htss Servlet` ?

Comment: my application named htss, htss Servlet is the main spring mvc DispatcherServlet.

Comment: post your dispatcher servlet

Comment: DispatcherServlet is the standardised Spring MVC servlet, class as: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. it was used to dispatch all income requests based on MVC work order. I used the annotation driven methods to developing my controller, and all MVC match is leading by controller class. If I put this JSP back to MVC, call it from controller, I think it will work fine, but if we take it out of MVC box, call the JSP by ajax from html, it said JSP not found, so I believe there are some thing wrong with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

$('#sign_in').load("Pagename.jsp");

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ,

WEB.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>htss Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to map all incoming requests to your spring servlet

Comment: Tried, not work. I tried the match <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> or <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>. Not work. But it works in MVC style. Not call JSP from html by ajax. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

I found out why?

As Spring has to protect source not be accessed directly from URL, all JSP under WEB-INF is not public accessible.

To enable individual JSP from URL, I need add one line in my htss-web-context.xml:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/jsp/testController" view-name="jsp/testController"/>
```

this line of code will let the URL request for /jsp/testController point to WEB-INF/pages/jsp/textController.jsp

So I can access this JSP from ajax call or from URL. But new problem came out, the Spring MVC container serve out this JSP with source code instead of executed JSP result. That is next problem.